# How to convert numbers which appear as text in a list to actual numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I convert List test to test1?

```
test = {{" 12.858  14.976  12.931"}, {" 12.858  14.739  13.663"}, {" \
      12.858  14.286  14.286"}, {" 12.858  13.663  14.739"}, {" 12.858  \
      12.931  14.976"}, {" 12.858  12.161  14.976"}, {" 12.858  11.428  \
      14.739"}};
test1 = {{12.858 , 14.976  , 12.931}, { 12.858 , 14.739 , 
      13.663}, {12.858  , 14.286 , 14.286}, {12.858 , 13.663 , 
      14.739}, { 12.858  , 12.931 , 14.976}, {12.858 , 12.161 , 
      14.976}, { 12.858 , 11.428 , 14.739}};
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces your expected result

```
Flatten[Map[ToExpression@*StringSplit, test, {-1}], 1]
```

There might be better ways to do this depending on how frequently you do this, how consistent your input is, how reliable it needs to be, whether you actually want intermediate results, etc.

Alternate without `Flatten`:

```
Map[Splice@*ToExpression@*StringSplit, test, {-1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
test = {{" 12.858  14.976  12.931"}, {" 12.858  14.739  13.663"}, {" \
      12.858  14.286  14.286"}, {" 12.858  13.663  14.739"}, {" 12.858  \
      12.931  14.976"}, {" 12.858  12.161  14.976"}, {" 12.858  11.428  \
      14.739"}};

Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Real"]] @@@ test
```

> {{12.858, 14.976, 12.931}, {12.858, 14.739, 13.663}, {12.858, 14.286,
> 14.286}, {12.858, 13.663, 14.739}, {12.858, 12.931,
> 14.976}, {12.858, 12.161, 14.976}, {12.858, 11.428, 14.739}}